# GoogleAppEngine: Incompatible php-cgi library version

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

**System configuration:**

- SDK version: 1.9.1
- Language: PHP 5.3.26
- OS: Mac OS X 10.6.8
- Python 2.7.6 (installed with Homebrew)
- MySQL running on port 3306

**Problem:**

I am trying to run an instance of **Wordpress** with **GoogleAppEngine** on localhost.

A colleague has OS X 10.7 with the same setup and does not receive an error.

The **GoogleAppEngineLauncher** is running the instance and the admin can be accessed through localhost:8005 but the log writes an error and the instance cannot be accessed on port 8080.

**Errors:**

When I open the browser (localhost:8080) this is the message I see:

> The PHP interpreter specified with the --php_executable_path flag
> ("/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine->default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php-cgi") is not compatible with the App Engine PHP >development environment.
>
> "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine->default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php-cgi -v" returned an error [-5]
> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
> Referenced from: /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine->default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php-cgi
> Reason: Incompatible library version: php-cgi requires version 7.0.0 or later, but >libcurl.4.dylib provides version 6.0.0

Below is the Log console output:

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
--skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=8080 --admin_port=8005
Python command: /usr/local/bin/python2.7
INFO     2014-03-29 17:50:41,177 devappserver2.py:682] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-03-29 17:50:41,239 api_server.py:341] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
WARNING  2014-03-29 17:50:41,249 simple_search_stub.py:1038] Could not read search indexes from /var/folders/XH/XHpGp6dGGtCU4lwb+UDGdk+++TI/-Tmp-/appengine.testapp.martinnrgaardgregersen/search_indexes
INFO     2014-03-29 17:50:41,261 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:49993
INFO     2014-03-29 17:50:41,279 dispatcher.py:182] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2014-03-29 17:50:41,404 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8005
ERROR    2014-03-29 17:50:42,248 php_runtime.py:223] The PHP runtime is not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 219, in new_instance
self._check_environment(php_executable_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 171, in _check_environment
version_stdout))
_PHPEnvironmentError: "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php-cgi -v" returned an error [-5]
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php-cgi
  Reason: Incompatible library version: php-cgi requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 6.0.0
```

If you are trying to dynamically load curl from your php.ini file, you will have to comment out the line "extension=curl.so" in the php.ini file, since this is not supported. But this is not the problem I have.

Comment: This is a known issue and should be fixed in the next update: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10405

Comment: The issue only seems to affect early versions of Mac OS X, 10.6 in particular.